# Uncaught Error: Class

Tags: php, php8

Это прямой путь к файлу

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/site.loc/App/Classes/FabricMethod/Posts.php

когда его пишу в require_once все работает

А это путь который возвращает мой автолоадер классов

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/site.loc/App/Classes/FabricMethod/Posts.php

полный совпадение

```
    function ClassAutoLoad($class): string
    {
        $prefix = '';
        $baseDir = __DIR__ . '/App/Classes/';

        $len = strlen($prefix);

        if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
            return 'Error';
        }

        $relativeClass = substr($class, $len);
        $file = $baseDir.str_replace('\\', '/', $relativeClass).'.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            echo 'File found ';
            var_dump($file);
            return $file;
        }
    }
```

Не понимаю почему ловлю ошибку((
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Posts.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я извиняюсь, а где в этом автолоадере собственно *лоад*?

Comment: @Ипатьев вот spl_autoload_register('ClassAutoLoad');

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали ответ

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    //echo 'File found ';
    ///var_dump($file);
    return $file;
}
```

тут returun надо заменить на require

Comment: надо убрать file_exists

Answer (score -1):

Вот самый простой автозагрузчик

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
  if  (file_exists('classes/' . $class . '.php'))
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Это будет загружать файлы из каталога ./classes . Вставляете это в index.php в самое начало. Код проверен.

Comment: Это **очень** плохой код. Показываю наглядно. Вот ваш [автозагрузчик курильщика](https://3v4l.org/RFJUG), а вот автозагрузчик [здорового человека](https://3v4l.org/CGhQU). **Вопрос:** какой из них позволяет понять, почему класс отсутствует?

Comment: плюс непонятно, чем этот код отличается от кода, который и так есть у автора вопроса. ну кроме очевидных ошибок из-за использования относительных путей